# How to sort on a field in indexedEmbedded

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I have an indexedEmbedded object with @OneToMany relation, inside a class, and want to sort with a field containded in that object.

When i call my method for search i got this exception:

"Unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'employees.id_forSort' (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues"

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
public Company {
   ....

  @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "students.", includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
  private Set<Employee> employees= new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public Employee{
   ....

  @SortableField(forField = "id_forSort")
  @Field(name = "id_forSort", analyze = Analyze.NO)
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
}
```

```
public class CompanySearchRepository{
....

  public List<Company> searchCompany(
          DataTablePagination pagination, Long id, SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        FilterField[] filterFields = validateFilterFields(searchCriteria.getFilterFields());

        // Sorting
        String sortField = "employees.id";

        Sort sort = getSort(sortField, pagination.getSortDirection());

        Query query;

        if (filterFields.length > 0) {
            query = getFilterableColumnsQuery(filterFields);
        } else {
            // global search
            query = getGlobalSearchQuery(searchableFields, searchCriteria.getSearchTerm());
        }

        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = getFullTextQuery(query);

        initPagination(
              fullTextQuery,
              sort,
              pagination.getPage(),
              pagination.getPageSize());

        List<Company> data = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
   }

   Sort getSort(String sortField, SortDirection sortDirection) {
    SortFieldContext sortFieldContext =
        getQueryBuilder().sort().byField(sortField.concat("_forSort"));

    return sortDirection.equals(SortDirection.ASC)
        ? sortFieldContext.asc().createSort()
        : sortFieldContext.desc().createSort();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. <strike>You named your sortable field `employees.id_forSort`, but when searching, you're using another field for sorts: `employees.id`. Use the field that is intended for sorts. Replace `String sortField = "employees.id";` with `String sortField = "employees.id_forSort";`</strike> My bad, I didn't see the weird code that adds a suffix to the field name in the `getSort` method. Then the message is strange. Would your index be empty, by any chance?
2. Sorts on multi-valued fields are not supported. You will likely get different results from one execution to the other, since the search engine has to select a value to use for sorts, and which value is selected is undefined.

Regardless of the technical aspect, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. You're getting `Company` instances as a result, and want them to be sorted by `Employee` ID, of which there are many for each `Company`. What does it mean? You want the company with the oldest employee first? Something else? If you're just trying to stabilize the order of hits, I'd recommend using the company ID instead.

Comment: i understand what do you mean, so we can not sort in indexedEmbedded field that is mentioned as @OneToMany. I'll sort with ```company.id```